# TextBox is Focused, but Can't Type Until I Click - XAML/C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an interesting situation where I set the focus on a searchbox using: `FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=SearchBox}"` which I found here: [Set the focus on a textbox in xaml wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872238/set-the-focus-on-a-textbox-in-xaml-wpf)

The good thing is that the search box is actually focused (I have a trigger that performs an action on focus), but I can't type into the textbox until I click on the textbox.

My textbox is very basic:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SearchBox"
         Grid.Row="0"
         style="{StaticResource SearchBox}" />
```

Any idea how I can allow the user to type right away as they open the control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.focusmanager.focusedelement?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Input_FocusManager_FocusedElement

Especially the remarks:

> The FocusedElement is the element which has logical focus for a specific focus scope. **This object may or may not have keyboard focus**. Keyboard focus refers to the element that receives keyboard input. For more information on focus, keyboard focus, and logical focus, see the Input Overview.

and:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.focusmanager?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

> An element with logical focus does not necessarily have keyboard
>   focus, but an element with keyboard focus will have logical focus. It
>   is possible to define a focus scope within a focus scope. In this
>   case, both the parent focus scope and the child focus scope can have a
>   FocusManager.FocusedElement

In the following post you'll find an example how to handle this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20299923/9295125

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this with `<window>` tag of the xaml page

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication30.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=SearchBox}">
<StackPanel>
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1"/>
<TextBox x:Name="SearchBox"
style="{StaticResource SearchBox}" />
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this was the original code I was using `FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=SearchBox}">` but unfortunately, that only sets the logical focus. I've implemented the accepted solution above and it works well!